# TO read all files in a folder in an order

Tags: python

i'm a beginner.i want to read all the files in a folder.for eg.files with name 1.csv,2.csv........10.csv,11.csv.....20.csv likewise.it sholud read as 1.csv,2.csv ......but for me it is reading as 1.csv,10.csv,11.csv.......19.csv,2.csv

i'm using the code :

```
import glob    
path = 'C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014//*.sec.gz'    
files=glob.glob(path) 
for list in sorted(files):      
    print list
```

Output:

```
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\1.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\10.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\11.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\12.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\13.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\14.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\15.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\16.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\17.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\18.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\19.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\2.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\20.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\21.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\22.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\23.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\24.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\25.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\26.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\27.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\28.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\29.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\3.sec.gz
C://test//08October2014//DATA_INTV_NEW//October082014\30.sec.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In string comparisons, `"0" < "1" < "10" < "2" < "20"` (lexicographical order). You'd have to name your files `"01"`, `"02"`, ..., `"09"`, `"10"`, ... for them to sort properly without extra effort.

If you can't do that, what you're looking for is called "natural sorting". There's a module that does that here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort